# iPhone location services show wrong place after connecting to XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation

After I connect my iPhone to XCode it starts showing that I am in center of London, however I am on north of Russia. I remember there was an option for simulating location in iOS simulator on Mac, but nothing like that for devices, so I don't know how to disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Uncheck　"Allow Location Simulation" in scheme setting.

[image]

2. Select "Don't Simulate Location" when run the app.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will try in 2 hours!